# Error Installing TensorFlow in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I tried installing TensorFlow on raspberry pi 3 according to Google's official documentation.

`pip install` did not give any errors, but I had to use keyboard interrupt since the terminal just showed successfully installed TensorFlow (not exact message)

But when I tried to import it into python i got this error message

> import tensorflow
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 52, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in 
>       from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
>     File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 94, in 
>       class DescriptorBase(six.with_metaclass(DescriptorMetaclass)):
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'with_metaclass'

Comment: Update your `six` module

Comment: six module already satisfied